# Unable to start the fatjar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, h2

I have a multi project application where the project structure is like

```
root
|
├───applicatiom-api-gateway
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   ├───java
... mainclass
... resource
├───application-commons-lib
│   └───src
│       └───main
│           └───java
... NoMainClass
...
├───application-service
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   ├───java
│       │   │   └───com
... mainClass
... resource
├───application-service-discovery
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   ├───java
.. mainClass
├───application-user-management-client-lib
│   └───src
│       └───main
│           └───java
.. mainClass
.. resource

├───application-web
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   ├───java
│       │   │   └───com
.. mainclass
.. resource
build.gradle
gradle.properties
```

The whole build.gradle file is

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '3.1.0'
    }
    ext {
        springCloudVersion = '2022.0.3'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")

    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    tasks.named('test') {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    configurations {
        testArtifacts
        developmentOnly
        runtimeClasspath {
            extendsFrom developmentOnly
        }
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
//        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        implementation('org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final')
//        implementation('io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0')
        annotationProcessor('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final')
        developmentOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }

    sourceCompatibility = '17'

    ext {
        projectName = "$rootProjectName-$project.name"
    }

    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }

    jar {
        enabled = true
    }

    task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
        from sourceSets.test.output
        classifier 'tests'
    }

    artifacts {
        testArtifacts testJar
    }
}

project(':application-commons-lib') {
    jar {
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}

project(':application-web') {
    bootRun {
        environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: environment.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE ?: 'local'
    }

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes "Main-Class": "com.application.application.web.WebApplicationService"
        }
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    }
}

project(':application-service-discovery') {

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes "Main-Class": "com.application.service.discovery.ServiceDiscoveryApplication"
        }
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    }

    dependencies {
        api('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server')
    }
}


project(':application-user-management-client-lib') {
    jar {
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    }
    dependencies {
        api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    }
}

project(':application-user-management') {

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes "Main-Class": "com.application.service.usermanagement.UserManagementService"
        }
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    }

    dependencies {
        api project(':application-commons-lib')
        api project(':application-user-management-client-lib')

        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        api('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
        api('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
        api('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0')
        api('com.h2database:h2:2.1.214')
        api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
        api('com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0')
    }
}

project(':application-api-gateway') {
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes "Main-Class": "com.application.service.gateway.ApiGatewayService"
        }
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    }

    dependencies {

        api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
        api('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway')
        api('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
        api('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
        api('com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0')

    }
}

project(':application-ledger') {
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes "Main-Class": "com.application.service.ledger.LedgerApplication"
        }
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    }

    dependencies {
        api project(':application-user-management-client-lib')

        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
        api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        api('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
        api('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
        api('com.h2database:h2:2.1.214')

        testImplementation('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.3')

    }
}
```

As I have five different sub projects or projects which will be deployed as independent fat jar. But when I run the jar task it creates the jar and when I start the start it displays that application started successfully but after that it closes the application. I mean application is not always listening to the port in fact it starts and closes the application

```
21:15:53.725 [main] INFO com.application.service.discovery.ServiceDiscoveryApplication -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
21:15:54.312 [main] INFO com.application.service.discovery.ServiceDiscoveryApplication -- Started ServiceDiscoveryApplication in 0.896 seconds (process running for 1.355)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Where as for other project of UserManagement it gives error for repository

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.application.service.usermanagement.repository.UserLoginOTPRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1824)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1383)
```

but when I start the application from Intellij then it runs without any issues.

May I know why this is happening ? I highly appreciate help.

I tried with multiple spring configuration changes for error but nothing is working.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.application.service.usermanagement.repository.UserLoginOTPRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: This exception is coming only for the application-user-management fat jar. Also the application starts successfully with gradle bootrun. If there is exception it should also come during bootrun also

Comment: Your bean wiring is wrong, regardless of how you run it.  Fix that.

Comment: Sounds like "it runs on my machine."  Not buying it.  Fix the problem where it lives and move on to the next one until everything is working.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).